# Hide exim4 version from email headers

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, exim

I've setup exim4 on a ubuntu 12.04 server.

When an email is sent, the current "Received" header has the following content:

```
Received: from user by example.com with local (Exim 4.76)
(envelope-from <user@example.com>)
id 1VmqiC-0005b0-PG
for user@domain.com; Sat, 30 Nov 2013 15:30:20 00:00
```

How can I hide the Exim version (4.76) currently being used by the server? Should I be concerned about security if the Exim version is known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define you own Received: header using [`received_header_text`](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html#SECTalomo) option. Looks like Ubuntu is using default one, so you can copy example from docs and just remove `$version_number` from it.

You should be concerned about security independently from showing version - [there was](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2012/CVE-2012-5671.html) security issues with exim of course. If you have patched system then this is matter of taste. If you hide it then you will be a bit more secure, but debugging of problem with mail from you on remote side will be maybe a bit harder.